# Как перевернуть объект UILabel

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

задумал я сделать зеркальное отображение в верхней половине экрана экземпляра UILabel, который находится в нижней половине экрана.
И не могу понять как!
Поможите!!

То есть мне нужно перевернуть вверх ногами экземпляр UILabel, чтобы текст выводился вверх ногами

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326720/objective-c-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel

Comment: на стекоферфлоу поворот, а тс нужно отразить текст, его через CGAffineTransformMakeRotation не сделать

Comment: Да, вы правы. Это я плюсанул, не глянув толком!

Comment: Ну тогда `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`

Comment: да для зеркального отображения использовал CGAffineTransformMakeScale с QuartzCore.framework;
а для поворота на 180 градусов - CGAffineTransformMakeRotation!

для новичков как я  - добавлю что величина угла указывается в радианах )

Всем спасибище!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня нет сейчас под рукой мака чтобы проверить, но насколько я помню это можно проделать присвоив `CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,1,0,0)` (поворот на 180 градусов вокруг x, [описание функции](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CATransform3DMakeRotation)) в `label.layer.transform` , только quartzcore не забудьте подключить.

Хотя должен признаться что у меня есть ощущение что отражать было бы правильнее всю половину экрана в целом, а не поэлементно, но я не могу с ходу назвать механизм как бы это можно было сделать, если только загнать всю половину экрана в отдельный класс и отрисовывать две вьюхи - обычную и отраженную или же отрисовать layer верхней половины второй раз через `renderInContext` снизу с повротом

Comment: спасибо все получилось )

Answer (score 0):

решение, как, перевернуть уже написал [@aknew](/users/2088/aknew) 
чтоб перевернуть именно половину экрана можно подложить две вьюхи, одна - верхняя половина экрана, врорая - нижняя, наполненная контентом. Переворачивать верхнюю, считывая с нижней контент.
Ну, это если нужно.